# onclick remove, html

Tags: javascript, html, css, webapp-net

I am working with webapp-net to build an application for iOS/android. in my app I have a form with some text fields. I want to have a "X" icon that usually appear on text fields when an input is entered. by clicking on that icon you can remove the whole input in just one click. The icon "X" appears only when an input is entered, when the textfield is empty the icon is not visible. If you could just give me an example of how to do it, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: There is `<input type="search">` which implements this feature automatically, but it does also have a magnifier icon on the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this simple html shows how to have an input field and a X button that calls a clean function when pressed

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="show();" id="text" /><div id="close" onclick="clean();" style="display:none">x</div>
```

Now the javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function show(){
      document.getElementById('close').style.display = ''; //shows the X button when text is entered;
   }

   function clean(){
      document.getElementById('close').style.display = 'none'; //hides the X button
      document.getElementById('text').value = ""; //clears the field
   }
</script>
```

Of course this lacks validations like what type of key is pressed to avoid showing the X button when you press SHIFT or CTRL

Comment: thank you, but this is not quit what I am looking for. I just used this code in my own code, and it works but not exactly what i want, the "x" is always printed on the next line, not the same line.

Comment: That's easily fixed. I don't know your code but you can just add a table and put the in different td or you can use div alignment

Comment: I used div alignment, but I still get the "x" on the next line. I dont get it within the text field, like you get on iphone when you enter a string value, I dont know if you get what I mean. I think in iphone they use some kind of image thing.

Comment: @ JSantos: thank you, I tried to make it work but i couldnt. i jave a <fieldset> and when I used your code within the field set, the layout get completely crappy. and nothing works.

Comment: You probably need to play around the CSS a little for it to match your design. See the same example with fieldset http://jsfiddle.net/tnaZn/15/